# How to union records of two stored procedures without knowing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

I have 2 stored procedures which returns same but unknown columns. I need to write a proc to combine results from both stored procedures. I tried OPENROWSET but problem is to provide the connection string in OPENROWSET function, even if I specify the connection string one time, it will be different for different environments and I think that will be the worst thing to change connection string each time I deploy the application in different environments or if the user is changed on server. Can someone help me to get this done in the best way.

I cannot write them as function since the procs are using temp tables.

```
Declare @connection nvarchar(200)
Declare @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @connection= 'Server=servername;initial 
catalog=dbname;user=abc,password=xyz';
Set @sql='SELECT * INTO #temp1
FROM OPENROWSET(
           ''SQLNCLI'',
           '''+ @connection + ''',
           ''EXEC sp_name '')'

Exec(@sql)
```

Comment: please show your code?

Comment: added the code snippet. i want this @connection variable to resolve itself for the same server on which this is executing.

Comment: Union will not work if the column structure are not the same. I would add the connection string in tblconn table. then pull with the select when you need it.

Comment: The procedures return same columns structure. If we add connectionstring in some table then still we will have to change it each time the application is deployed on different servers. any other idea, please?

Comment: configuration file

Answer (score 0):

```
--- creating a temporary table
CREATE Table #Dynamic_Temp_Table (_field_only_for_create_ INT )

--- Addition of fields from the first recordset from the first procedure
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SELECT @SQL=ISNULL(@SQL+',','ALTER TABLE #Dynamic_Temp_Table ADD ')+name+' '+system_type_name 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('exec sp_proc_first', NULL, NULL) 
    order by column_ordinal
exec sp_executesql @SQL 

--- Remove of the first unused column
ALTER TABLE #Dynamic_Temp_Table drop column _field_only_for_create_

--- Addition of the result from the first procedure
INSERT INTO #Dynamic_Temp_Table
exec sp_proc_first

--- Addition of the result from the second procedure
INSERT INTO #Dynamic_Temp_Table
exec sp_proc_second

--- result:  exec sp_proc_first UNION ALL exec sp_proc_second
select * from #Dynamic_Temp_Table
--- result: exec sp_proc_first UNION exec sp_proc_second
select DISTINCT * from #Dynamic_Temp_Table
```

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work, as the PO mentioned "the procs are using temp tables", dm_exec_describe_first_result_set will not be able to determine the metadata

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not easy at all....

You can change your stored procedures to just create and populate a global temp tables (no select), then you can select both with an union.

To use OPENROWSET as you are doing it in your current approach you will need global temp table too, But as you mention that your stored procedures are using Temp Tables, OPENROWSET, OPENQUERY or sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set will not be able to determine the metadata to create the temp table.

Another option is to change your stored procedures to use variable tables instead of temp tables, then the metadata could be redetermined. @chrszcpl's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55632401/10932521 is a very good solution if you are able to do that.

If this is not possible (I assume that this isn't, otherwise the columns would't be unknown) because you are using dynamic sql in your procedures, or you simply can't touch those procedures for any reason, I think that the cheapest solution is create a third stored procedure which returns the dynamic columns definition that the other procedures will return..